How do I query ravendb documents relative to today?
Is there a way to query documents in ravendb relative to today? Something like
from someCollection where changeDate < today() - '5 days'

I don't find any documentation on what is possible to compare dates. I'm not sure if this is even possible, or if this must be checked in code instead of as a query. It would be convenient to be able to query documents by change date.

See the following example where the query returns documents based on time criteria:

Some class:
public class TaskToDo
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

Store some documents:
var myTask1 = new TaskToDo()
{
    Description = "todo1...",
    DueDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)
};
var myTask2 = new TaskToDo()
{
    Description = "todo2...",
    DueDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10)
};

session.Store(myTask1);
session.Store(myTask2);
session.SaveChanges();

Query for documents:
var overDueTasks = session.Query<TaskToDo>()
    .Where(x => x.DueDate < DateTime.Today)
    .ToList();

// Query results will include only `myTask1` which is overDue


Some introductory discussion about this can be found in Listing 2.9 under this link:
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#querying-ravendb
